# sql statement with datediff and colums from db

Tags: mysql, sql, datediff

I have a problem with DATEDIFF in this sql-statement:

```
$sqlab = "select * from _database12";
$sqlab .= " where DATEDIFF (d,EntryDate,StartDate) < 14";
$sqlab .= " and EntryDate >= '".$_POST["from"]."%'";
$sqlab .= " and EntryDate <= '".$_POST["till"]."%'";
$sqlab .= " order by EntryDate DESC";
```

Without DATEDIFF this works perfectly, but i need to get it to work with DATEDIFF in order to only get those entries, where StartDate minus EntryDate is less than 14 days.

EntryDate ans StartDate are colums in database12. Can I use these?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You are using erroneous format of DATEDIFF - a Transact-SQL DATEDIFF(datepart , startdate , enddate)? [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms189794.aspx).

In MySQL, here is reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff,
DATEDIFF(enddate, startdate) given in days, has no format/datepart argument.

You can try this if StartDate >= EntryDate:

```
$sqlab = "SELECT * FROM _database12
 WHERE DATEDIFF(StartDate, EntryDate) < 14
 AND EntryDate >= '" . $_POST["from"] . "'
 AND EntryDate <= '" . $_POST["till"] . "'
 ORDER BY EntryDate DESC";
```

Comment: Hey jacouh,

thanks for your help. I've tried yours and at least I get some entries, now. But it seems that it doesn't count right.

It also gives me entries, where StartDate minus EntryDate is more than 14.

What do I have to change?

Comment: You should check the field type of EntryDate (Date, String, Timestamp), and what's their real value, please also give examples.

Comment: The field type is DATE. For both - EntryDate and StartDate. An Example: DatasetA (EntryDate: 2013-11-07, StartDate: 2013-11-11) does and should show up, but: DatasetB (EntryDate: 2013-11-04, StartDate: 2013-11-19) does also show up, although it shouldn't.

Comment: I've updated the code to use DATEDIFF(StartDate, EntryDate), as StartDate >= EntryDate.

Comment: Wow - what a stupide mistake by me. Sorry for misusing your time. Thanks